# Python- can i use -date.strptime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I try to change the format of the day (without the time), and I get the next error.
please explain to me the problem here :

```
from datetime import date
temp = '01/01/2000'
Date.strptime(temp, '%d/%m/%Y')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Date' is not defined
```

Comment: Python is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: You imported `date`, but try to use `Date`, so that's never going to work.

Secondly, `strptime` is only on `datetime`, not `date`, but it's not hard to get a `date` out of it with the `datetime.date` method:

```
from datetime import datetime
temp = '01/01/2000'
mydate = datetime.strptime(temp, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.datetime` instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
temp = '01/01/2000'
print(datetime.strptime(temp, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

The problem with your code is that `date` does not have the `strptime` attribute and also the usage of it was `Date` with uppercase D unlike `date`.

According to @MadPhysicist, Python is case-sensitive.